# How to connect java code and c++ library in extreme conditions

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have code on Java, which call a C++ library(dll). Connection architecture is

```
Java - > wrapper.dll(Win32) -> target.dll(Win32)
```

wrapper.dll - library from previous programmer. I have not actual code for this and compiled library fir Win32 platform.
target.dll - thirdparty library, where is no source code, but have versions for all platforms.

How i can mirate to Linux with it?

Comment: It's not possible without the source code.

Comment: I have to ask, how did your company get into this mess? If wrapper.dll is a simple JNI type wrapper, you should be able to make some educated guesses as to what it does. Maybe even do a bit of disassembly. If it's more complex than that then I think you're going to struggle. Blame the management.

Comment: Either you find a linux replacement for target.dll and write a new wrapper (Or just use jna instead), or you try to get the entire thing running on wine or so. (yes including jvm)

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the wrapper and compile for required platforms yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to run the Windows version of java through Wine. Currently there is no way to link to a windows DLL at least on Linux.

Otherwise you'll have to rewrite the wrapper or use JNA to call functions in the original library directly. This is probably easier than you think.

Comment: Thank you for link to JNA. It is very helpfull for me.